# How can I troubleshoot a mount issue when moving to Systemd (14.04 > 16.04)?

Tags: mount, fstab, systemd

I have a data server and two VMs.  The first VM, `clone14`, runs Ubuntu 14.04.  The second VM, `clone16`, was cloned from `clone14` and then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

Both VMs have the exact same `/etc/fstab` file that includes a line mounting a directory from the data server, whose IP address is 99.99.99.99 in this example:

```
99.99.99.99:/data/NFS/primary            /disks          nfs     rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60 0 0
```

Everything always works as intended on `clone14`, but `clone16` will not consistently mount the remote directory.  Sometimes it will partially mount it, with only some of the subdirectories and files available within the `clone16:/disks/` mountpoint.

The big change from 14.04 to 16.04 is Systemd instead of Upstart as the init system.  Systemd is *supposed* to accept `fstab` entries without a problem, but something is clearly messing up here.

I've searched for "update fstab for systemd" and related terms, but I haven't found anything I can interpret as useful.  This post contains almost my entire knowledge of fstab and mounting in Linux, so please use small words when responding.  As always, context and explanation in your comments and answers are valuable to me and others who find this page in the future.

How do I figure out what's wrong and correct it?

Comment: I think that you need to replace `nfs` with `cifs` in your mount statement.

Comment: @heynnema What makes you say that?  I can't find any indication that `nfs` won't work with Ubuntu 16.04/Systemd, or that it has been superseded by `cifs`

Comment: Before asking the question, did you try cifs to see if it works for you?

Comment: @heynnema No, I didn't.  Wouldn't the data server need to be configured for `cifs`?  And isn't `cifs` a Windows thing?

Comment: Network shares is not my area of expertise... I just seem to remember that cifs has been the fix for a few questions that I've seen. Maybe I'm wrong. But... it would take as long to try cifs, as we've been discussing it. If it doesn't work, I can admit to being wrong :-) You may also have to change some of the optional parameters in your statement.

Comment: systemd will translate that line from fstab into a `disks.mount` unit, so you can start troubleshooting the problem by looking into `systemctl status disks.mount` to check its status and `journalctl -u disks.mount` to see the logs related to that unit. If the unit looks stopped/failed, see what happens with `sudo systemctl start disks.mount` or `sudo systemctl restart disks.mount`. Are there other mounts under `/disks`? Nested mounts might be part of the problem you seem to be having... Post output of commands above (edit your answer), that should help us figure it out.

Comment: Post also output of `systemctl cat disks.mount`, that's also useful.